# what's the different between redis.v4 and redis.v5 in golang package

Tags: go, redis

Currently I'm doing some project to build cache data using Redis using Go language.
I'm using Redis version 4 from [gopkg.in/redis.v4](https://gopkg.in/redis.v4). We have the plan to upgrade it to [redis version 5](https://gopkg.in/redis.v5).

But I've the following issue before attempt to update version :

- What is the good thing about redis 5 compare to redis 4
- I tried to find the changelog but I could not, any changelog for this update?
- any changes to make after updating the redis 4 to redis 5 ? like function ?

Hopefully someone could help me regarding this issue. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no official changelog, but on github you can use the compare function to see at least high-level what changed. In this case it was not much as far as i see.

https://github.com/go-redis/redis/compare/v4...v5

On my own tests i have not seen any non-working functions to v4.